# Data manipulation sql result using stuff approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, data-manipulation

*Edited to add condition if have boxNo > 1 row

Let say I have table #DOC with result string sql like this :

this table doesn't have any primary we can assume that polNum and boxNo pair are unique,

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null | qwe1234 |
| 111111 | ff/55 | rto1235 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | rto1235 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234 |
| 222222 | null | fgh1234 |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | qaz1234 |

I need have collection from batchNum and boxNo become like this.

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null |  |
| 111111 | ff/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 222222 | null |  |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | qaz1234 |

Need to manupulated batchNum row with comma separated based polNum and not empty boxNo and put same row. But if any condition boxNo is empty or null batchNum will put same polNum row.
I was tried using stuff approach
result still goes wrong.

SELECT DISTINCT polNum, boxNo ,
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+batchNum FROM #DOC a WHERE a.polNum=d.polNum or a.boxNo = d.boxNo FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') batchNum
FROM #DOC d

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ff/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 222222 | null | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | qaz1234 |

Comment: What happens if a `polNum` has _three_ records, two of which have non NULL box numbers?  Can you add more sample data to get the rules across?

Comment: HI Sir, i was added more sample data value of table.

Comment: @GarindaBurnama I removed my answer since it doesn't apply to your version of SQL Server.